# Extracting the differences between two python nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am attempting to extract the differences between two nested dictionaries.

I have installed DeepDiff, which looked like the best option for what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to determine how to change the output so it provides the dictionary values rather than a set which I cannot index. Is there a better way to alter the output (rather than converting the output back to a dictionary)

```
from __future__ import print_function
from deepdiff import DeepDiff
knownAPs = {'WLC1': {'10.1.1.1': {'72.6': ['AP22', 'city'], '55.1': ['AP102', 'office']}}, 'WLC2': {'10.1.1.2': {}}}
discoveredAPs = {'WLC1': {'10.1.1.1': {}}, 'WLC2': {'10.1.1.2': {}}}
ddiff = DeepDiff(knownAPs, discoveredAPs)
print(ddiff)
if 'dic_item_added' in ddiff.keys():
    print('Item added to known: ' + str((ddiff['dic_item_added'])))
if 'dic_item_removed' in ddiff.keys():
    DisAssociatedAPs = (list(list(ddiff['dic_item_removed'])))
    for i in DisAssociatedAPs:
        keypath = (str(i).strip('root'))
        print("AP's removed from known database: " + str(knownAPs + keypath))
if 'values_changed' in ddiff.keys():
    print('Item changed: ' + str((ddiff['values_changed'])))
```

Error

```
{'dic_item_removed': set(["root['WLC1']['10.1.1.1']['72.6']", "root['WLC1']['10.1.1.1']['55.1']"])}
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'str'
```

Preferred Output

```
{'dic_item_removed': set(["root['WLC1']['10.1.1.1']['72.6']", "root['WLC1']['10.1.1.1']['55.1']"])}    
AP's removed from known database: ['AP22', 'city']
AP's removed from known database: ['AP102', 'office']
```

Comment: can you give some examples. e.g. some inputs and expected output

Comment: @Hooting, I have added an example

Comment: @Stanley, unfortunately I cannot use the DeepDiff module in this environment since the customer is running 2.6

Comment: @zeepi See the other answers, If none of them work, [edit] your post as to why it won't work.

Comment: I have installed DeepDiff as suggested and I am now trying to change the output provided

Comment: I will ask this as a new question.